# Changing javascript code with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Yeah this might look crazy but I just want to know if this is possible or not. I have something like this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    if(variable == 10){
        $('img').attr('src','img/image.jpg');
    } else {
        $('img').attr('src','img/image-2.jpg');
    }
});
```

Now, the problem is I have more than 2 photos (I have 10 categories of 2 photos each) but I don't want to create 10 variables and copy that block of code 10 times. So I wondered if you can make something like changing that 'img/image...jpg' part with another javascript command or so.

Comment: `var images = { 10: 'image.jpg', ..., }, defaultImg = 'image-2.jpg;`

Comment: On button click what is your exact need?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use the variable as part of the image name, e.g.

```
 $('img').attr('src','img/image-' + variable + '.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the names of your images - if you control the names, then you can make them work better with dynamic variables using a concept called string concatenation:

```
var num = 2;
$('img').attr('src', 'img/image-' + num + '.jpg');
```

This code will render `img/image-2.jpg`.  If you change the `num` variable, the image source will change accordingly.

Comment: I did understand what you said, but I don't know how to execute it, so I'll be doing this: instead of putting  `$('img').attr('src','img/image.jpg');` inside I'll put a variable with it so I can change the value of the variable, thanks anyway for replying!

Comment: if your image names are in a row, does a loop solves the problem?